# Supervisor spinning up multiple celery and worker processes on aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, daemon, supervisord

I am running the setup that follows(just showing the beat setup for simplicity) for daemonizing my celery and beat workers on Elastic beanstalk. I am able daemonize the processes successfully however too many processes are being spawned.

Current Output

```
root     20409  0.7  9.1 473560 92452 ?        S    02:59   0:01 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp worker --loglevel=INFO
root     20412  0.6  7.8 388152 79228 ?        S    02:59   0:01 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp beat --loglevel=INFO
root     20509  0.0  7.1 388748 72412 ?        S    02:59   0:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp worker --loglevel=INFO
root     20585  0.6  7.7 387624 78340 ?        S    03:00   0:01 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp beat --loglevel=INFO
root     20679  1.1  9.1 473560 92584 ?        S    03:01   0:01 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp worker --loglevel=INFO
root     20685  0.0  7.1 388768 72460 ?        S    03:01   0:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp worker --loglevel=INFO
```

Desired output as achieved by after the environment deploys running kill -9 $(pgrep celery)

```
root     20794 20.6  7.7 387624 78276 ?        S    03:03   0:01 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp beat --loglevel=INFO
root     20797 24.3  9.1 473560 92564 ?        S    03:03   0:01 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp worker --loglevel=INFO
root     20806  0.0  7.1 388656 72272 ?        S    03:03   0:00 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3.6 /opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp worker --loglevel=INFO
```

celeryBeat.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
      
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/celery -A djangoApp beat --loglevel=INFO
```

supervisor.conf

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/opt/python/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
;chmod=0700                 ; socket file mode (default 0700)
;chown=nobody:nogroup       ; socket file uid:gid owner

[supervisord]
logfile=/opt/python/log/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=10MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/opt/python/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
directory=/opt/python/current/app    ; (default is not to cd during start)
;nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///opt/python/run/supervisor.sock

[program:httpd]
command=/opt/python/bin/httpdlaunch
numprocs=1
directory=/opt/python/current/app
autostart=true
autorestart=unexpected
startsecs=1                   ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures (default 3)
exitcodes=0,2                 ; 'expected' exit codes for process (default 0,2)
killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
redirect_stderr=false
[include]
files: celery.conf
```

celery.conf

```
[program:beat:]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=sh /opt/python/etc/celeryBeat.sh
directory=/opt/python/current/app
; user=nobody
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery-beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=60

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 60

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

container commands

```
container_commands:
  01_celery_tasks:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/files/celery_configuration.txt > /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh && chmod 744 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
    leader_only: true
  02_celery_tasks_run:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/files/beat_configuration.txt > /opt/python/etc/beat.sh && chmod 744 /opt/python/etc/celeryBeat.sh"
    leader_only: true 
 
  03_celery_tasks_run:
    command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/run_supervised_celeryd.sh"
    leader_only: true
```